# Install indigo to ubuntu 14.04.2(testing)

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to install indigo to ubuntu 14.04.2, which is testing version of ubuntu trusty, but I met conflict with HWE packages from utopic as follows:

```
$ sudo aptitude install ros-indigo-rviz
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 libdrm-dev{a} libgl1-mesa-dev{a} libgl1-mesa-dri{a} libgl1-mesa-glx{ab} libglapi-mesa{a} libglu1-mesa-dev{a} libllvm3.4{a} libphonon4{a} libpyside-dev{a} libpyside-py3-1.2{a} libpyside1.2{a} libqt4-dev{a} libqt4-dev-bin{a} libqt4-opengl-dev{a} libqt4-qt3support{a} libqtwebkit-dev{a} libshiboken-dev{a} libshiboken-py3-1.2{a} libshiboken1.2{a} libx11-xcb-dev{a} libxcb-dri2-0-dev{a} libxcb-dri3-dev{a} libxcb-glx0-dev{a} libxcb-present-dev{a} libxcb-randr0-dev{a} libxcb-shape0-dev{a} libxcb-sync-dev{a} libxcb-xfixes0-dev{a} libxshmfence-dev{a} libxxf86vm-dev{a} mesa-common-dev{a} phonon{a} phonon-backend-gstreamer{a} phonon-backend-gstreamer-common{a} phonon-backend-gstreamer1.0{a} python-pyside{a} python-pyside.phonon{a} python-pyside.qtcore{a} python-pyside.qtdeclarative{a} python-pyside.qtgui{a} python-pyside.qthelp{a} python-pyside.qtnetwork{a} python-pyside.qtopengl{a} python-pyside.qtscript{a} python-pyside.qtsql{a} python-pyside.qtsvg{a} python-pyside.qttest{a} python-pyside.qtuitools{a} python-pyside.qtwebkit{a} python-pyside.qtxml{a} python-qt4-dev{a} qt4-linguist-tools{a} qt4-qmake{a} ros-indigo-map-msgs{a} ros-indigo-media-export{a} ros-indigo-python-qt-binding{a} ros-indigo-rviz shiboken{a} x11proto-dri2-dev{a} x11proto-gl-dev{a} x11proto-xf86vidmode-dev{a}
0 packages upgraded, 61 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 24.8 MB of archives. After unpacking 138 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgl1-mesa-dri-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1 which is a virtual package.
                          Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
xserver-xorg-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 0~) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
                       Conflicts: libgl1-mesa-glx (>= 0~) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
                       Conflicts: libglapi-mesa (>= 0~) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
libgl1-mesa-glx : Conflicts: libgl1 which is a virtual package.
libglapi-mesa-lts-utopic : Conflicts: libglapi-mesa but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3 is to be installed.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
Internal error: found 2 (choice -> promotion) mappings for a single choice.
```

HWE packages are needed to run ubuntu 14.04 in my hardware.
How can I install indigo packages resolving the conflicts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202829/install-indigo-to-ubuntu-14.04.2(testing)/) by [iori](https://answers.ros.org/users/21595/iori/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2015-02-10

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-05-06**:
Other answer suggested: http://answers.ros.org/question/203610/ubuntu-14042-unmet-dependencies/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're running the testing version of 14.04.2 with utopic backports it seems like they have not ironed out all the gl libraries for that case. You will probably need to dig in and try to manually select the dependencies you need, or push back upstream to make sure that the backports you are using are compatible. From your output we're not asking for any specific version so it's a conflict in your upstream apt sources.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0